# format text inside a group class and span (Justify text)

Tags: html, css, format

I have this html code

```
<section class="group5">
    <p ><span class="purple">1)</span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec molestie. Sed aliquam sem ut arcu. Phasellus sollicitudin. 
    Vestibulum condimentum  facilisis nulla. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nulla nonummy. Cras quis libero.</p>
    <p ><span class="purple">2)</span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec molestie. Sed aliquam sem ut arcu. Phasellus sollicitudin. 
    Vestibulum condimentum  facilisis nulla. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nulla nonummy. Cras quis libero.</p>
    </section>
```

and this css

```
p {
    margin-bottom:7px;      
    color:#161414;
    }

a, p a {
    text-decoration:underline;
    color:white;
    }
    a:hover {color:white;}

.group5 {
    float: left;
    width: 350px;
    position: relative;
    background:transparent;
    padding:15px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    }

.purple{
    font-size:50px;
    color: #663366; 
    float:left;
    padding:12px;
    margin:20px;
}
```

How can I format de paragraph, I mean to justify the text in the paragraph?

I get the following unformated result

[image]

I was reading that there is

```
 div
{
text-align:justify;
text-justify:inter-word;
}
```

But that only works on IE...

Comment: Format the paragraph how? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I would like to Justify the text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can also use

```
<p align="justify">.. . . . . . . </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution was

```
p {
    margin-bottom:7px;
    text-align: justify; 
    color:#161414;
}
```